# Como puedo organizar las columnas en fila

Tags: sql

Hola amigos tengo esta consulta en sql que me devuelve esta tabla

```
select distinct
asignatura_nombre, nota, examenexamen_id
from estudiante inner join  examen_matricula_facultad_cum_carrera_estudiante_asignatura
on estudiante.estudiante_id = examen_matricula_facultad_cum_carrera_estudiante_asignatura.estudiante_id,
asignatura,
examen
where asignatura.asignatura_id= examen_matricula_facultad_cum_carrera_estudiante_asignatura.asignatura_id 
and examen.examen_id = examen_matricula_facultad_cum_carrera_estudiante_asignatura.examenexamen_id
order by asignatura_nombre
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que me devulviese la nota segun el id e examen por columnas sera de esta forma

1. IDexamen  1  2  3
2. Calculo I 4  3  5
3. Filosofia 3  5  5

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos utilizas?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar pivot para convertir filas a columnas, pero lo que pide no se ajusta muy bien a SQL puro. Está pidiendo 2 resultados diferentes:

- El encabezado con los ids de los exámenes es un result set.
- La lista con la asignatura y las notas en forma columnar correpondiente a cada examen id es otro resulset.

Usar pivot requiere que sepa de antemano la cantidad de columnas que va a tener, por lo que tendría que rankear las notas y tener un máximo de columnas ordenadas de mejor a peor, lo cual no sé si llene su requerimiento.

Considere que puede terminar con demasiadas columnas y se puede volver muy difícil de leer.

Asumo que está preparando un reporte. Si es así le recomiendo que explores tablas pivote en herramientas como excel, power bi o SSRS. Esas herramientas ofrecen soluciones más poderosas para requerimientos de reportes.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15